# SQLite3, Python: fetchone() works on table1 but not table2 but fetchall() works on both

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this one: I have three tables in my SQLite3 db and the data rows of table1 don't show up when I try to access them in a for-loop with `fetchone()`, but the data rows of my table 3 show up just fine using the for-loop and `fetchone()`.  A `fetchall()` is the only method that works to access the data in table1, and `fetchall()` also works on table3. I have one row of data in table1 and 3 text columns only, and many rows of data in table3 and 6 text columns only. This interactive-mode example shown exhibits the same problem as my non-interactive scripting does:

```
>>> cur.execute('select * from ' + tablename1)
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x021A3420>
>>> print '\n'+str(cur.fetchall())

[(u'OMAHA / COUNCIL BLUFFS, NEBRASKA, US', None, u'green')]
>>> cur.execute('select * from ' + tablename1)
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x021A3420>
>>> for row in cur:
...     data = cur.fetchone()
...     print data
...
None
>>> cur.execute('select * from '+tablename1)
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x021A3420>
>>> cur.execute('PRAGMA table_info('+tablename1+')')
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x021A3420>
>>> data = cur.fetchall()
>>> for d in data:
...     print d[0], d[1], d[2]
...
0 REGIONUPPERCASE TEXT
1 REGION TEXT
2 REDGREEN TEXT

>>> cur.execute('select * from '+tablename3)
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x021A3420>
>>> cur.execute('PRAGMA table_info('+tablename3+')')
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x021A3420>
>>> data = cur.fetchall()
>>> for d in data:
...     print d[0], d[1], d[2]
...
0 REGIONUPPERCASE TEXT
1 REGION TEXT
2 REDGREEN TEXT
3 COORDSLAT TEXT
4 COORDSLONG TEXT
5 CLHREF TEXT

>>> cur.execute('select * from ' + tablename3)
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x021A3420>
>>> for row in cur:
...     data = cur.fetchone()
...     print data
...
(u'BIRMINGHAM, ALABAMA, US', u'birmingham, Alabama, US', u'red', u'33.5206608', u'-86.80249', u'
(u'FLORENCE / MUSCLE SHOALS, ALABAMA, US', u'florence / muscle shoals, Alabama, US', u'red', u'3
(u'HUNTSVILLE / DECATUR, ALABAMA, US', u'huntsville / decatur, Alabama, US', u'red', u'34.72849'
(u'MONTGOMERY, ALABAMA, US', u'montgomery, Alabama, US', u'red', u'32.3668052', u'-86.2999689',
(u'ANCHORAGE / MAT-SU, ALASKA, US', u'anchorage / mat-su, Alaska, US', u'red', u'61.340307', u'-
(u'KENAI PENINSULA, ALASKA, US', u'kenai peninsula, Alaska, US', u'red', u'59.8785222', u'-150.3
(u'FLAGSTAFF / SEDONA, ARIZONA, US', u'flagstaff / sedona, Arizona, US', u'red', u'34.8262376',
```

Like I said, the `fetchall()` works for table3, I just didn't post that output here.  I haven't gotten to table2 so far (this is a newly created db that I haven't gotten fully functional yet) so let's not worry about table2 right now. It will be more similar to table1 than to table3. In other words, tables1 and 2 columns schema are subsets of table3 columns schema.

I wonder if the table or data in it is being or got corrupted. Is that possible. This just seems so strange to me. I don't know how to troubleshoot this one or where to start, so I ask for help from anyone who can.

Thank you all for being so helpful to others!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looping *over the cursor*. This yields the data *already*. By the time you call `fetchone()` the row has already been served.

Just use the loop variable, it contains each row result as you iterate:

```
cur.execute('select * from ' + tablename1)
for row in cur:
    print row
```

Your loop over `tablename3` only sees half the rows; you fetch one row by iterating, ignore that row, fetch the next with `cur.fetchone()` and print that one, repeating the process in a loop.

Use either iteration *or* `fetchone()` and `fetchall()`. Don't mix the two.

`fetchone()` would be used to fetch just *one* result row, for example:

```
cur.execute('select * from ' + tablename1 + ' WHERE unique_column=?', ('somevalue',))
row = cur.fetchone()
if row is not None:
    # there was a matching row, rejoice
    print row
```

Comment: ? I don't quite understand.  I trust you do see that I am performing the very same command structure for both tables? I'll keep reading your answer until I figure out what you mean. OOHH!  So you mean the first row of data in table3 is getting skipped? And since table1 only has one row, it looks like nothing is there?  GOT IT NOW!  Thank you!!!

Comment: @kenneth558: you are using a `for` loop to loop over the cursor object. **That yields results**. That means the cursor moves on to the next row too as you do that, so `row` is the first row from your database, `data = cur.fetchone()` tries to retrieve the *second* row. But your table only has one row, so that call returns `None`.